# Does discolored building cable need to be replaced?

Tags: wiring

I’m seeing some runs of 12/2 white cable having brown discoloration, spanning multiple feet. But then other areas in the same area aren’t discolored. Should I replace these?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the dirt clean off, or is it discoloration of the cable itself?

Comment: Discoloration of the outer cable sheath is not a reason for replacement. There are endless possibilities as to how the discoloration happened. The cables you show, however, are seriously lacking in required support.

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @kreemoweet

Comment: Deal with the mice that have been piddling all over them. Hope they haven't been chewing anywhere.